# solidity two dimentional mapping or array

Tags: solidity

I want to use two dimensional mapping or array but one key should be address  and the other key is a number ,how can I do this?
Similar to Mapping (address , uint256=> unit)
How to do it? Use struct? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can have a `mapping` of a `mapping`:

```
mapping (address => mapping(uint256 => uint256))
```

Comment: Because mapping uint256=>uint256 will be different for each key address in this way 0x123=>(2=>99) and 0x234=>(2=>99) should be different since actually it is a kind of two dimensional array similar like value[0x1234][2]